# Https server work on macOS but not work on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, https, server, cocoaasyncsocket

I write a simple https server which only response "Hello world".
The project use lib `CocoaAsyncSocket` to communicate.

```swift
func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didAcceptNewSocket newSocket: GCDAsyncSocket) {
    let session = Session(socket: newSocket)
    session.delegate = self
    sessions.append(session)

    slog("https server receive new socket")
    newSocket.enableBackgroundingOnSocket()
    if let items = self.sslItems { // Enable https
        newSocket.startTLS([kCFStreamSSLIsServer as String: kCFBooleanTrue, kCFStreamSSLCertificates as String: items, kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain as String : kCFBooleanFalse])
    }
    session.begin()
}

public func begin() {
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.readData(to: termData, withTimeout: -1, tag: SocketReadTag.readRequestHeader.rawValue)
    slog("read request header")
}
```

I can not read any data. Why?

Comment: Did you disablea pp transport security?

Comment: How to disable it? My Info.plist  have an item NSAppTransportSecurity : NSAllowsArbitraryLoads